# sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected NULL, expecting CONST_INT (or 5 other tokens) near 'NULL,1448734444)'

Tags: syntax, null, sphinxql

The error is this:

> sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected NULL, expecting CONST_INT (or 5 other tokens) near 'NULL,1448734444)'

How delete this index `id = 1448734444`, thank you I don't know how to use sphinx,and where is sphinx's database

Comment: You have a syntax error which means your SQL query is not correct. Fix the query and you can perform the delete. If you want more help, write down the *exact* SQL query you're using.

Comment: when i run this code ' python index_worker.py '

Comment: Well - we **can't see** your screen, nor can we read your mind - **SHOW US** the code you're using that's causing this error !

Answer (score 0):

I solve the probeem ,this is delete index

$ mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P9306
mysql> desc bbs_post;

mysql> select * from bbs_post where match('mobei');

mysql> select * from bbs_post where match('beibei');
mysql> select * from bbs_post where match('test');